# How to use Norwegian language iphone?

Tags: iphone, fonts, uilabel

How can i use Norwegian characters to show them in UILabel in my application.

if i use it directly it shows garbage value.

Comment: Code please? And the actual "garbage" might also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The characters should work. I'm using a UILabel which loads from a nib file into the view of a ViewController. The label works in Times New Roman and Palatino (and presumably other fonts) when I set the text with the following code: `[myLabel setText:@"ÆØÅ æøå"];` . I would try copying and pasting that line directly and see what happens.

I would guess that you're getting your characters from somewhere whose representation is not quite right in `NSString` terms. I grabbed these from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norwegian_alphabet). (I don't speak Norwegian so I'm not sure if you need other non-English alphabet characters - as far as I could see these were the only ones.)